# Should I see PC boot to BIOS if I only attach 24-pin to the motherboard?

Tags: boot, desktop-computer

I am attching only the 24-pin and the vga. I am not seeing any thing display on the monitor. When I have every other cables plugin, I see nothing either, that's why I only have 24 and vga plugged in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not, you also need to plug in the seperate power connector for the CPU - this is either 4 or 8 pins, and is right next to your socket.

Look for something like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I believe i have taken that out a while ago when I was cleaning the fans. I just plugged in my 4-pin. I still don't see any display. I have also taken our the cmos battery just 5 mins ago and put it back. Does it contribute to my issue? suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: and again, only vga, 4 and 24 pins.

Comment: hmm, does your PSU have a switch? is it on? are the power switch headers connected?

Comment: Hi. I can use the front power button to turn on, and I can feel cpu buring. fan is running. should it mean I have headers pin plugged in? Yes. i have that plugged in in order for the power switch and the dvd eject

Comment: Yes, it should. I'm about all out of ideas at this point

Comment: what did you miss?

Answer (score 5):

In order to get to or past POST you need the following items.

1. A processor.
2. RAM.
3. A power supply plugged into the motherboard and the 4-6-8 pin plugged into the processor power junction on the motherboard.
4. The fans plugged into the junctions on the motherboard.
5. Optional, the graphics card if no on board graphics.

Without those 4, or 5 things, you will get just a black screen, you can ignore 4 if you wish, but it will over heat quickly and get you back to not being able to POST till it cools down.

Further info on POST.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test